# Making an event listener for a range slider from an html form

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have been trying to get this eventlistener for my range input to work onmouseup after the client has selected the number on the slider though it won't pick it up.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
document.getElementById("wordInput").onkeyup = function(){
    
    sliderInt = parseInt(document.getElementById("slider").value);


    newWord = letterShifter(sliderInt, this.value.toLowerCase());
    document.getElementById("topcipher").innerText = newWord;
};

document.getElementById("slider").onmouseup = function(){
    newWord = letterShifter(document.getElementById("slider").value, document.getElementById(wordInput).toLowerCase());
    document.getElementById("topcipher").innerText = newWord;
};
```

The first wordInput eventlistener works (just takes a word from a text input) but the slider on mouse up one does not. What could I do to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post a full code example, but onmouseup event perfectly works on slider.

[My example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bs24v8dj/):

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="slider">
<span id="topcipher"></span>

 window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
   document.getElementById("slider").onmouseup = function() {
    sliderInt = parseInt(document.getElementById("slider").value);

    document.getElementById("topcipher").innerText = sliderInt;
  };  
});
```